# Moving Partitions Around

Tags: hard-drive, partitioning, ssd, easeus-partition-manager

I have two physical SSD disks and one HDD.

One SSD is about 120Gb and the OS is installed into that SSD and by the way it has only one partition (apart from the OS-reserved).

Another SSD is about 180Gb. For now, I have cut about 128Gb from it and I want to extend the first SSD adding these 128Gb.

HDD has only one partition as well and I don't need to do with it anything.

As far as I understand, I need to move the unallocated space to the right side of the OS-drive. To do that, I also need to move the OS-reserved partition to the left, at first.

I installed EaseUS software and I don't see the way of moving partitions, everything is just locked.

Look at the following video on YouTube I uploaded, you'll see how everything looks like on my machine: https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=0D232FRMgPk

What am I doing wrong?

Comment: You can't edit partitions on an drive which contains the OS you are using (at least in Windows anyway). You'll want to use something like a [Linux Live USB](https://www.linuxliveusb.com/) to boot from, and then use [GParted](https://gparted.org/download.php) (this page has install commands as well as ISO files you can use to create a bootable USB for this specific purpose). There is a good tutorial on GParted [here](https://www.dedoimedo.com/computers/gparted.html) but the interface is fairly friendly

Comment: @Sam3000 So, GParted can extend the OS-partition?

Comment: Yes it should do everything you need, you can even just drag the partitions around with your mouse so it's nice and easy. The key point is that you cannot edit partitions on a disk that is running an operating system at the time.